# Menschen aus aller Welt haben diese Region bereist

Tags: word-usage

Can I use "Fläche" in this context: Menschen aus aller Welt haben diese Fläche bereist.

Comment: No. *Fläche* means *area* only in the sense of a measure.

Comment: To be more exakt: *Fläche* emphasizes *area* or *flatness*. *Region* emphasizes the *location* of a region.

Comment: @Kilian Foth: Fläche is not necessarily flat, for instance Kugeloberfläche, Zylinderoberfläche.

Comment: @Uwe: There is a difference between _Fläche_ (_plain_) and _Oberfläche_ (_surface_). _Kugelfläche_ doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, "Fläche" does not work here. You could use "Gebiet" or "Gegend", though.

Comment: _Region_ might also be a good fit.

Comment: @raznagul yes, but "Region" was already mentioned in the title.